# org.apache.jasper.JasperException in jsf application

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, tomcat, icefaces

I am getting following error while open jspx page.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /login.jspx(9,54) Document root element "ui:composition", must match DOCTYPE root "composition".
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parse(JspDocumentParser.java:214)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:239)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
```

JSF file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition
    template="/jsp/common/classic-template-login.jspx"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
        xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" >

    <div align="left"><ui:define name="title">OES Admin</ui:define></div>

    <ui:define name="toolbar">
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="pageView">

    <ui:decorate template="/jsp/common/page-include-template.jspx">

        <ui:define name="pageName" ></ui:define>

        <ui:define name="pageActions">
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="pageContent">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/login.jspx"/>
        </ui:define>        
      </ui:decorate>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be wary of your terminology: this is a facelets page, not a JSP page. Just because you map your url to '*.jspx' doesn't make it so. You may think that a little thing, but facelets is a complete replacement for JSP technology and works quite different under the hood.

The only thing I can spot that is a difference between my own facelets pages is that mine have an additional namespace declaration.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Comment: OP is actually using JSPX, not Facelets (see filename in exception message and the JSP compiler calls in stacktrace). JSPX is a leftover of ICEfaces 1.x recommendation (from long time before Facelets was introduced). Facelets tags actually don't work at all in JSP(X) and hence this error. OP was most likely reading completely outdated ICEfaces tutorials/guides.